# How to initialise a custom object list in Powershell 5.1?

Tags: powershell, collections, initialization, custom-object, powershell-5.1

What I want to achieve:
Create a list of files, show their name and version and sort alphabetically.

My attempt:

```
class File_Information
{
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][string]$Name
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][string]$FileVersion
}

$FileList = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[File_Information]

foreach ($file in Get-Item("*.dll")){
  $C = [File_Information]@{
    Name = $file.Name
    FileVersion = $file.VersionInfo.FileVersion
  }
  $FileList = $FileList.Add($C)
}

foreach ($file in Get-Item("*.exe")){
  $C = [File_Information]@{
    Name = $file.Name
    FileVersion = $file.VersionInfo.FileVersion
  }
  $FileList = $FileList.Add($C)
}

Write-Output $FileList | Sort-Object -Property "Name" | Format-Table
```

My Powershell version:

```
Prompt> Get-Host | Select-Object Version
Version       
-------       
5.1.19041.1320
```

My problems and/or questions (first is the major question, second and third are optional):

- I don't know how to initialise a list of custom objects (I've been looking on the site, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241435/initialize-custom-object-lists-in-powershell) only gives the possibility to initialise with an existing value, while I want to initialise to an empty list).
  The error I receive is:

  ```
    You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
    At line:... char:...
    +   $FileList = $FileList.Add($C)
    +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
  ```
- Currently I ask for the same thing twice: I have tried `Get-Item(*.dll,*.exe)`, `Get-Item(*.dll;*.exe)` and `Get-Item(*.dll|*.exe)` but none of them worked.
  Is it even possible to search for different patterns?
- Until now I am struggling just to get `Write-Output $FileList` working. Are the other two commands (`Sort-Object -Property "Name"`, `Format-Table`) correct?

Comment: You keep overwriting `$FileList` with `$null` - remove the `$FileList =` assignment operation and it'll work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use a class and a List object for that at all?
You can just use `Select-Object` on the files of interest you gather using `Get-ChildItem` and output the needed properties there:

```
# capture the resulting objects in a variable $result
$result = Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\path\to\the\files' -File -Include '*.dll','*.exe' -Recurse |
          Select-Object Name, @{Name = 'FileVersion'; Expression = {$_.VersionInfo.FileVersion}}

# output on screen
$result | Sort-Object Name | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

---

To use two different name patterns on `Get-ChildItem`, you need to also add switch `-Recurse`, or append `\*` to the path.
If you do not want recursion, you will need to add a `Where-Object` clause like:

```
$result = Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\path with spaces' | Where-Object {$_.Extension -match '\.(dll|exe)'} |
          Select-Object Name, @{Name = 'FileVersion'; Expression = {$_.VersionInfo.FileVersion}}
```

Comment: Just to give you an idea: now my command looks like this and it's not working: `Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\...\Server Machine' -Include '*.dll','*.exe' | Select-Object ...`

Comment: @Dominique Please see the code I have just edited in to not do recursion. As long as you use quotes around the path, spaces in that should not be a problem. If you also have square brackets in the path (`[]`), then change `-Path` into `-LiteralPath`. Why you say the `-File` switch doesn't work is beyond me, because your PowerShell version is high enough to understand that.

Comment: @Dominique Haha, you saw my edit even before I could comment on it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your code actually works fine, with two small exceptions.

**Problem #1**: overly restrictive property attributes can cause errors

First off, in your custom class, you should be very sure you want to append this attribute `[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]`, as it will throw a non-terminating error when you try to new up an instance of a class if any one of the properties with this attribute are null.

For instance, on my PC, I have a dll or two with empty `file.VersionInfo.FileVersion` properties.  When that happens, PowerShell will fail to create the object, and then also fail trying to add the object to the list because there is no object.  Very confusing.

**Fix** : remove the attribute of ValidateNotNullOrEmpty unless you're 100% positive this info is present.

Next up, ***the real problem here*** is that in each of your for-each loops, you're accidentally breaking your `FileList` object which you correctly setup in your code as it is already.

**Problem #2**: Small syntax issue is causing your list to be nulled out, causing errors for every op after the first.

The issue happens in this line below, which I will explain.

```
$FileList = $FileList.Add($C)
```

The List.Add() method's return type is either a void or an integer (it's only an int when you provide a generic object, if you provide the type specified for the list, in your case being your custom class of `File_Information`, it provides a VOID.)

Void is the same as null.  We can confirm that the output of .Add is the same as `$null` with the following code.

```
PS> $FileList.Add($c) -eq $null
True
```

You can see the output for the various ways of calling `.Add()` in detail by just typing out the method name with no parameters, like this.

```
PS> $FileList.Add

OverloadDefinitions                                                                                                                 
-------------------                                                                                                                 
void Add(File_Information item)       #< the one you're using!                                                                                              
void ICollection[File_Information].Add(File_Information item)                                                                       
int IList.Add(System.Object value)
```

So in effect your for each loops are adding an item to the list, then resaving the variable $FileList to the output of the .Add method, which is a void, or null in other words.  You're killing your own list!

We don't need to resave `$FileList` as we go, since the purpose of a list is to be populated in code, and the only thing we have to do is to call the `.Add()` method.

**Fix**: stop killing your list object in your loops by changing these lines in your code.

```
#before
$FileList = $FileList.Add($C)

#after
$FileList.Add($C)
```