# How to use cmdlet inside an expression

Tags: powershell, checksum, powershell-5.1

As explained in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71295992), I would like to have the name and the file version of a list of files inside a directory.

Until now, thanks to [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo), I already have this:

```
$result = 
  Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\path with spaces' | 
    Where-Object {$_.Extension -match '\.(dll|exe)'} |
    Select-Object Name, 
                  @{Name = 'FileVersion'; 
                    Expression = {$_.VersionInfo.FileVersion}}
```

Now I would like to add the checksum to that.
In order to achieve this, this is what I have tried:

```
$result = 
  Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\path with spaces' | 
    Where-Object {$_.Extension -match '\.(dll|exe)'} |
      Select-Object Name, 
                    @{Name = 'FileVersion'; 
                      Expression = {$_.VersionInfo.FileVersion}}, 
                    @{Name = 'CheckSum'; 
                      Expression = {Get-FileHash($_).Hash}}
```

So, basically, I have added another "thing" with a name and an expression, which I tried to add (in case this seems ridiculous: this is my first Powershell day :-) ).
This does not work, but there is no error message: it's just as if the question for the checksum is not even there.

Does anybody know how I can solve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your parens are miss-placed `(Get-FileHash $_.FullName).Hash`

Comment: As aside, default value for `-Alogrithm` is SHA256. If you're looking for MD5 or something else you would need to add as example: `(Get-FileHash $_.FullName -Algorithm MD5).Hash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is actually giving an error however errors inside the *expression script block* are quietly ignored. See [**Notes**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2#notes) of the official docs.

```
PS /> @{} | Select-Object @{Name = 'Something'; Expression = { throw }}

Something
---------
```

If you inspect the your [`$Error` automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#error) you would likely see something like:

```
PS /> $Error[0]

Get-FileHash: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
```

The right expression should be:

```
Expression = {(Get-FileHash $_.FullName).Hash}
```